# object Object issue with display objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, constructor

Hey I have a constructor objects in JS and wants to see all of that object, why did pops up [object Object] like here? 
[`MyCodeFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/upwLvhs5/).

Comment: `JSON.stringify(pers);`

Comment: Beacuse `var pers = new Person("John", "Colin", 47, "blue");'` is object you can not directly append object. You  have to stringify  it.

`document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pers);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all the object keys and populate the new created `persArr` with the object `pers` properties values.

Finally in only one call you can get all the properties values properly separated by comma `persArr.join(', ')`:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}

var pers = new Person('John', 'Colin', 47, 'blue'),
    persArr = [];

Object.keys(pers).forEach(function(key) {
  persArr.push(pers[key]);
});

document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = persArr.join(', ');
```

```css
#data {
  display: flex;
  width: 120px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="data"></div>
```

Even better you can create a new method in your Person prototype to properly get the info you want:

```js
function Person(first, last, age, eyecolor) {
  this.first = first;
  this.last = last;
  this.age = age;
  this.eyecolor = eyecolor;
}

Person.prototype.getInfo = function() {
  return `${this.first} ${this.last}, ${this.age} years old and ${this.eyecolor} eyes.`;
}

var pers = new Person('John', 'Colin', 47, 'blue');
document.getElementById('person').innerHTML = pers.getInfo();
```

```html
<div id="person"></div>
```

If you want to print the object for debugging purposes:

- Output in console:

  `console.log(pers);`
- Output as an string, in the html, by using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

  `document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pers, null, 4);`

Answer (score 0):

The objects when directly given to html for display [object object] will be displayed as that is a default behaviour

If you really want to display in html there are two ways

1) Iterating the object properties

```
for(var i in pers ) {
   document.getElementById("data").innerHTML =  document.getElementById("data").innerHTML + pers[i] + ',';
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upwLvhs5/2/

2) Stringifying the object to JSON

```
 document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(pers)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/upwLvhs5/3/